# Php Search engine error

Tags: php, search, search-engine

im trying to code a search engine.
It works apart from that if i enter a query like west coast, i also get the result of East coast. This happens because the keywords in east and west contain coast as a individual word.

However i want to seperate the two using this line of code:

```
<?php
$k = $_GET['k'];
$terms = explode(" ", $k);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Search WHERE ";
foreach ($terms as $each){
    $i++;

    if($i == 1)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";

}
```

If i echo that out the keywords using in the search form do get separated, but further on they don't
how can i fix this?

```
<?php
$k = $_GET['k'];
$terms = explode(" ", $k);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Search WHERE ";
foreach ($terms as $each){
    $i++;

    if($i == 1)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";

}
if($k == "" || $k == " ")
{
    echo "<p> Please enter a valid search term."; //If search is empty or contains only a space.
    exit;
}
//connect to database
mysql_connect("LOCALHOST" ,"ROOT" ,"PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("DATABASE");
$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        echo "<h2><a href ='$link' class='searchcolor' color='#a8a8a8'> $title</a></h2>
            $description<br />
            This page contains information about \"<b>$query</b>\"<br /><hr>";
    }

}
else
    echo "No results for \"<b>$k</b>\"";

//disconnect
mysql_close();


?>
```

Comment: use MATCH() rather than like so MATCH('East Coast') it returns a weighted search results so you can order by relevance ie: east coast has higher relevance than west coast so you can make sure that east coast appears at the top and west coast appears on say page 200.  Note this only works with full text indexing and myiasm tables.  You can do it with innodb tables but you have to do it in code not query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Search WHERE keywords LIKE '%west%' OR keywords LIKE '%$coast%';
```

Will return results which match *either* of those keywords because of the `OR`. Use `AND` if you want the results to match all keywords.

I.e. change

```
$query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
```

To

```
 $query .= "AND keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
```